# Multiple date array with same value by name on Highcharts

Tags: arrays, reactjs, join, highcharts

I want to custom highcharts, but before that I am stuck how to combine or manage multiple arrays with the same date and name value from JSON

```js
// sample data JSON
const dataJson = [
  {
    "day": 1,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "John",
    "value": 1000.0
  },
  {
    "day": 1,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "Joe",
    "value": 2000.0
  },
  {
    "day": 2,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "John",
    "value": 2000
  },
  {
    "day": 2,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "Joe",
    "value": 500
  },
  {
    "day": 2,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "Joe",
    "value": 500
  },
  {
    "day": 2,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "Jane",
    "value": 500
  },
  {
    "day": 3,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "John",
    "value": 1500
  },
  {
    "day": 3,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "John",
    "value": 2000
  },
  {
    "day": 4,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "Jane",
    "value": 1500
  },
  {
    "day": 5,
    "month": 10,
    "name": "Janet",
    "value": 1000
  }
]
```

I want implement the above JSON into this highchart function:
Like merge day and month then show it in xAxis categories be day/month.
ex: day 1 and month 10 => 1/10.

Merge value same name in same day. Sample JSON day 2 Joe has 500 and 500. So in highchart series value for Joe is 1000 for day 2

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: 'Total fruit consumption, grouped by gender'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['1/10', '2/10', '3/10', '4/10', '5/10']
},

yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Number of fruits'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
            'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
    }
},

plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [1000, 2000, 3500, 0, 0],
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [2000, 1000, 0, 0, 0],
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [0, 500, 0, 1500, 0],
}, {
    name: 'Janet',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1000],
}]
```

});

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aliezio/5jLug7da/13/) is link to my fiddle

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what your JSON data means - the name is the name of the series, value is a `y` value, but what about the day and the month?

Comment: Hi. I want the day and month merge and display it in xAxis categories like 1/10. You can see first data day 1 and month 10. Please check my fiddle for detail see the result. Thank you

Comment: And i want too merge value same name in same day. Sample JSON day 2 Joe has 500 and 500. So in highchart series value for Joe is 1000 for day 2

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this way is maybe not the most performant to accomplish this task, but it gets the job done:

```js
const dataJson = [{
    day: 1,
    month: 10,
    name: "John",
    value: 1000.0,
  },
  {
    day: 1,
    month: 10,
    name: "Joe",
    value: 2000.0,
  },
  {
    day: 2,
    month: 10,
    name: "John",
    value: 2000,
  },
  {
    day: 2,
    month: 10,
    name: "Joe",
    value: 500,
  },
  {
    day: 2,
    month: 10,
    name: "Joe",
    value: 500,
  },
  {
    day: 2,
    month: 10,
    name: "Jane",
    value: 500,
  },
  {
    day: 3,
    month: 10,
    name: "John",
    value: 1500,
  },
  {
    day: 3,
    month: 10,
    name: "John",
    value: 2000,
  },
  {
    day: 4,
    month: 10,
    name: "Jane",
    value: 1500,
  },
  {
    day: 5,
    month: 10,
    name: "Janet",
    value: 1000,
  },
];

const res = dataJson.reduce((acc, cV) => {
  if (acc[cV.name]) {
    acc[cV.name] = {
      day: {
        ...acc[cV.name].day,
        [cV.day]: acc[cV.name].day[cV.day] ?
          acc[cV.name].day[cV.day] + cV.value :
          cV.value,
      },
    };
  } else {
    acc[cV.name] = {
      day: {
        [cV.day]: cV.value
      }
    };
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

let result = [];
Object.keys(res).forEach(name => {
  const values = {
    name
  };
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (res[name].day[i]) {
      data.push(res[name].day[i]);
    } else {
      data.push(0);
    }
  }
  values.data = data;
  result.push(values);
});

console.log(result);
```

In the `res` variable, I change the array of json data into an object with the name and day as keys. If the day exists, I add the new amount to the current one, otherwise I create the key.

After that, I loop through the object and check whether values exist in a given day. If yes, then I push it to the data, if no, I push 0 to the data. My solution is for 5 days, but you can easily adjust it for any given amount of days.